# Disable layout rendering in controller filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pjax

Using pjax, trying to disable layout if `request.headers['X-PJAX']` is true.

Instead of placing this logic in all my routes, is there a way to setup a filter that does this?

```
after_filter lambda {
  if request.headers['X-PJAX']
    # disable rendering with layout
  end
}

def show
  render layout: application
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work

```
SomeController < ApplicationController
  layout choose_layout

  def actions
  .
  .
  .
private
  def choose_layout
    request.headers['X-PJAX'].present? ? false : 'application'
  end
end
```

If you only ever use the application layout, I guess you could put it in the Application controller to have it applied to all controllers automatically.